# In AWS, how do I log IIS and EventLog data to CloudWatch from new instances are spun up in an AutoScaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

I followed the instructions here for our Windows Server 2016 instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartWindows2016.html which works well for instances that are already running, but I need advice as to how to apply my same, custom json to any new instances that are spun up from AMI in an AuotScaling group.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have two options:

**1. Bake your JSON in a new AMI.**

Start an instance, put you JSON in it, create a new AMI from this instance.

**2. Use 'user data' to create/download JSON at startup.**

Your Auto Scaling Group is attached to a launch configuration. You an create a launch configuration with any script that will execute at instance startup. This script can create or download JSON config you need. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html

Comment: But how do I get that json applied to the Run Command and the AWS-ConfigureCloudWatch document on a new instance?  It's not enough to simply have the json file; I need to use it.